# Does SmtpClient.Send with attachments included hold a lock on the attached file?

Tags: c#, email, smtp, smtpclient

I'm currently debugging an issue and couldn't find an answer to this question in [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

I have the following code:

```
if(attachmentFileName != null && File.Exists(attachmentFileName))
{
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachmentFileName, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet));
}

using(SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true })
{
    try
    {
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }
    catch(SmtpException ex)
    {
        if(attachmentFileName != null && ex.StatusCode == SmtpStatusCode.ExceededStorageAllocation)
        {
            //Need to still send the mail. Just strip out the attachment & add footer saying that attachment has been stripped out.
            mail.Attachments.Clear();
            mail.Body += "\n\nNote: Please note that due to outbound size limitations, attachments to this email have been stripped out.\n";
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

At a higher level (the caller of this method), I have the following:

```
try
{
    SendEmail(recipients, alertTitle, body, alertID, subjectPrefix, merchantIDValue, attachmentFilePath);
}
finally
{
    if(tempFile != null)
    {
        File.Delete(tempFile);
    }
}
```

I deployed the code to our test environment and I am now getting the following exception in our error logs:

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\fileName.zip' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
   at AlertDelivery.CreateAttachmentFile(String attachmentData, String merchantID, String reportTitle) in d:\svn\trunk\Solution\Alerting\AlertDelivery.cs:line 143
   at AlertDelivery.TrySendAlert(String merchantID, String reportTitle, Int32 alertID, String alertTitle, String attachmentData, String attachmentFilePath, String body, Boolean isReport, String subjectPrefix, List`1 recipients) in d:\svn\trunk\Solution\Alerting\AlertDelivery.cs:line 110
   at AlertingService.ProcessAlertEvents(Object parameters) in d:\svn\trunk\Solution\Alerting\AlertingService.cs:line 174
```

Line 174 is the `File.Delete(tempFile);` line in the caller code.

Does SmtpClient maintain an asynchronous lock on attachments after `SmtpClient.Send` has been called?  Any other conspicuous problems?

Comment: Apparently there is / was a funny in the client. http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Dec/18/SmtpClient-and-Locked-File-Attachments This suggests not trying to tidy up til OnSendComplete fires

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to encapsulate your `mail` variable with a using statement
Something like this

```
public void SendEmail(...)
{
    using(MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
    {

      .... your code above
    }

}
```

this will force the dispose call for the MailMessage object and that call also disposes any attachments.

Comment: If I'm returning from a method, this should happen implicitly, right?  I don't return MailMessage itself, is the problem.

Comment: But you can't count on deterministc GC runs to free unused objects.

Comment: true, but I rather prefer to let C# do its job.  I did change it to do this, and will let you know if it doesn't work.  Thanks!

Comment: @MarcRoussel difficult to say. Why don't you post a new question with details of your code? Perhaps more people will look at your problem and something could be found to help you better.

Comment: Solved.  The code was disposing MailMessage.Attachments but not the MailMessage.  After disposing the MailMessage which itself dispose the Attachments it worked.

Answer (score 7):

It certainly does, until you dispose of the MailMessage object.

Comment: Ok, but is Smtp.Send a blocking call, or does it send the mail asynchronously?

Comment: it blocks until the smtp server takes possession of the message, or returns an error, or times out.  It does not block until the recipient receives the message.

Comment: But does it block my C# code until `smtp.Send(mail)` is done, releasing the lock on the file?

Comment: yes.  that is the definition of `block`  Your code will stop executing at `smtp.Send(mail)` until the server is done with it.

Comment: The file lock is NOT released until you dispose of your MailMessage object.  mail.Dispose(), or a using statement.